# How can I pipe output from my local sound card to MPD?

Tags: networking, audio, sound-card, mpd, webcast

I would like to "Pipe" the output of my local sound card to MPD on a networked music server.

Anyone have any suggestions how to go about this?
I'm thinking maybe i can make a live MP3 stream? maybe over the web, or over the intranet?
(IIRC MPD supported MP3 streams, i've had Internet radio steams going (though I didn't set them up)>

I'm not very experienced with MPD, or with webcasts.
OS wise I don't particularly mind.
At the moment the computer I'm looking at running it on has XP installed, but I'm going to be whipping it soon.

Comment: I'm not sure if this belongs here, or on server fault.

Comment: @oxinabox.ucc.asn.au: i think superuser is just fine.

Comment: @oxina: doesn't really strike me as SF material; better here.  the [music-player-daemon] tag is unnecessary (the [mpd] tag is already used for MPD questions) so i replaced it with a more generic [audio] tag.

Comment: btw, what OS will you be running?  as i understand it, the PulseAudio sound system used in recent Ubuntu versions can direct all audio output from one system to another over the network.  dunno if you can output from PulseAudio to MPD tho.  what kinds of audio are you looking to send?  generic system event sounds?  media player output?  game sounds?

Comment: I haven't yet made up my mind what I'll be running, prob, not ubunto, it bugs me. strong contenders (there are varied): Windows 7, Archlinux, a close derivitive of gentoo, or BSD, Or debian.
As I said I want to direct the output of my sound card. that means everything. The output of the soundcard is avaiable as a sound card input, (sometiems called Line Out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hava a look at ices2 and Icecast2.
ices2 is a source client for broadcasting local audio output (ALSA/OSS) to an icecast2 server.